# SQL Server stored procedure run every day at the same time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scheduled run of stored procedure on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server)

I have a stored procedure with the name `transere_orders`. I have to run it every day at 22:00

How can I set scheduled tasks with SQL Server 2005

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schedule it on SQL Server Agent.

ahh, here's an old question (you should'a searched for it first) [Scheduled run of stored procedure on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/sheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-ms-sql-server)

oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a job in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

after connecting to your server, Click on jobs category and then Add a new job,

scheduling it is ease as 1, 2, 3.