# Every-minute stored procedure executing using Quartz.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, quartz.net

I want to implement every-minute database stored procedure executing in ASP.NET MVC web site using Quartz.Net. I wonder how can I exec the procedure with and without parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a matter of [configuring the scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_1.html) and then in the [job implementation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_2.html) call the stored procedure. Also if you are using SQL Server haven't you considered doing this [using the server agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server)?

Comment: I have no ability to use SQL Server Agent, that is why I have to use Quartz.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to use Quartz.net with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net) for implementing Quartz in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use [Reactive.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg577609) and drop it in a Windows service (it takes just a few minutes with [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/)).

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    .Subscribe(i => ExecuteStoredProc());
```