# How to run a stored procedure automatically every day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How do I set up to run a stored procedure automatically every day in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a SQL job http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Job scheduler in the sql agent.  Sql express doesn't include it so I just have a batch file run as a scheduled task to run it.
-James

Answer (score 1):

Was discussed here:
[Scheduled run of stored procedure on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Under SQL agent you need to go to the job scheduler and create a job that runs the stored proc.  Once you have created the job you can create one or more schedules for the job. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx