# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure - run once a day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run this query for every day over the past year. Is there a way to automate the process and get back a list of `MaxAgentsLoggedIn` for each day?

Thanks in advance

```
select top 1 
     dIntervalStart IntervalStart, count(cName) MaxAgentsLoggedIn
from IAgentQueueStats
where cReportGroup = '*'
   and cHKey3 = '*'
   and cHKey4 = '*'
   and tAgentLoggedIn > 0
   and dIntervalStart >= '2013-09-24 00:00:00'
   and dIntervalStart <= '2013-09-24 23:59:59'
group by 
   nDuration, dIntervalStart
order by 
   MaxAgentsLoggedIn desc;
```

Definition

```
      [cName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [cReportGroup] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[cHKey3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[cHKey4] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[cType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[dIntervalStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[nDuration] [int] NOT NULL,
[nEnteredAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nGrabbedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nLocalDisconnectAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAlertedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnswered] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAcdSvcLvl] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl1] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl2] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl3] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl4] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl5] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAnsweredAcdSvcLvl6] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl1] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl2] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl3] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl4] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl5] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAbandonAcdSvcLvl6] [int] NOT NULL,
[tGrabbedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAnsweredAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[mtAnsweredAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAbandonedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tTalkAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tTalkCompleteAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nHoldAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tHoldAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAcw] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAcw] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAcwComplete] [int] NOT NULL,
[nExternToInternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nExternToInternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nInternToExternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nInternToExternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nInternToInternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nInternToInternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tExternToInternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tExternToInternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tInternToExternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tInternToExternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tInternToInternCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tInternToInternAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nAcwCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAcwCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
 [nTransferedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nNotAnsweredAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAlertedAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nFlowOutAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tFlowOutAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[nStartWaitAlertAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nStartActiveAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nStartHeldAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nEndWaitAlertAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nEndActiveAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nEndHeldAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nTransferWithinAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nTransferOutAcdCalls] [int] NOT NULL,
[nDisconnectAcd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentLoggedIn] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentAvailable] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentTalk] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentOtherBusy] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentOnAcdCall] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentOnOtherAcdCall] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentInAcw] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentOnNonAcdCall] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentDnd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentNotAvailable] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentAcdLoggedIn] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentStatusDnd] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentStatusAcw] [int] NOT NULL,
[tAgentLoggedInDiluted] [int] NOT NULL,
[tStatusGroupFollowup] [int] NOT NULL,
[tStatusGroupBreak] [int] NOT NULL,
[tStatusGroupTraining] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue1] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue2] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue3] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue4] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue5] [int] NOT NULL,
[CustomValue6] [int] NOT NULL,
[I3TimeStampGMT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[SiteId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[SubSiteId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[nLocalDisconnectAgentAlertAcd] [int] NULL,
[nLocalDisconnectAgentAcd] [int] NULL,
[tAgentAcdLoggedIn2] [int] NULL
```

Comment: This discussion shows how to schedule the stored procedure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Comment: What type of DB? In an Oracle DB, use a dbms_job tied to a Stored Procedure, in mySQL, look into this doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating the query by day, can you include the day in the query and then group by the day?

[Question 113045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype) has an answer that shows how to pull just the date from the date time using

```
convert(date, dIntervalStart)
```

If you add this date to your query, you can then query the max(AgentsLoggedIn) from the result and get a list by day.

```
select theDay, max(AgentsLoggedIn) MaxAgentsLoggedIn
from (
    select convert(date, dIntervalStart) as theDay
         dIntervalStart IntervalStart, count(cName) AgentsLoggedIn
    from IAgentQueueStats
    where cReportGroup = '*'
       and cHKey3 = '*'
       and cHKey4 = '*'
       and tAgentLoggedIn > 0
       and dIntervalStart >= '2013-09-24 00:00:00'
       and dIntervalStart <= '2013-09-24 23:59:59'
    group by 
       nDuration, dIntervalStart ) as q
group by theDay;
```

Comment: Hi the tAgentloggedin is the amount of time the agent stayed logged in not the timestamp. The queury works correctly for one day. I am just trying to run for multiple days.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the table definition - at least the definition of the relevant columns?  That might make it easier to help.

Comment: Hi G_A. I have added the table definition