# How to calculate the next run date for a SQL Server agent job

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I am developing a custom system for scheduling task & I am following Microsoft SQL Server Agent approach to schedule task.

I have replicated `sysschedules` table for capturing users scheduling occurrences and timings.

Now I need to know how SQL Server get the `Next_run_date` and time from this table.

I have found a solution on the internet which are using `sysjobhistory` table to get the next run date, but in my case, I have an only `sysschedules` table. So, what is the formula to calculate the `next_run_date` and time for any job?

Note: I am looking for entire code, concept/algorithm will work for me.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Express you could consider using [Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server/41909818#41909818). If you need application level scheduling you could search for [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Writing own bulletproof scheduler is not a trivial task.

Comment: my plan like, I have one job which run every 30 min and it will checks next_run_date of schedule tables and based on it if it falls within that schedule then it populate metrics value in database tables. It is background Database process

Comment: Then use Task Scheduler