# How to write a polling service in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to two tables `employee` and `department`.

**Employee**

```
Id, Name, JoiningDate, SpecialRegistrationDone, DepartmentId
```

**Department**

```
DepartmentId, Name
```

There is a special department with `DepartmentId  = 2` and `Name = "AI"`.

There is a Java service pushing the data to `Employee` and `Department` tables.

Now, I have to write a polling service (polling frequency once in 15 minutes) which satisfies the condition

```
select e.* 
from Employee e
inner join Department d on e.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
                        and e.DepartmentId = 2
                        and e.JoiningDate > cast(GetDate() as date)
                        and e.specialRegistrationDone = 0
```

If there are any records fetched then call a Web service say http://specialdepartmentregistration/register and pass the employee details there.

One way to write is to write a Java service which polls the database and execute this query, get the results and calls the web service for resultset.

I am looking at a away to create a service on the SQL Server side only which executes the query and call the web service. How can I write that ? Is it even possible in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Just an idea, but wouldn't it be much easier to implement a cron job calling a server-side script that takes care of querying the db and, if needed, call the web service?

Comment: You can't write anything _inside_ T-SQL to push data out to a web service. It has to be something external. Although you could use system com stored procedures, this is unreliable and unsupported

Comment: @ChrisBE - Yes that's one option, but I was exploring any option on the sql server side. I was just wondering if I can use triggers but still be able to call a web service.

Comment: Why do this at all? SQL Server Agent already runs jobs periodically. The *database* can't push data to other services unless you use Service Broker either. A job's script can do so easily though

Comment: To put it another way, the database **shouldn't** call long running, blocking, external services like a web service. A scheduled job on the other hand can do so quite easily

Comment: How will the *database* throttle requests to that service to avoid flooding it? How will it handle error responses?  How will it retry failed requests? All those things are trivial for a small console application or script. Doing so in SQL isn't possible

Comment: BTW I use SSIS, custom-made command line tools and scheduled jobs to poll million-row tables every 15 minutes and call airline web services for new data, store that into the database and combine all of those things together. Calling a web service HttpClient, implementing retries with Polly, creating a processing pipeline wit throttling using TPL Dataflow is easy. Making even a single HTTP call in T-SQL, even using SQLCLR would be too tricky, never mind retries, concurrent requests and throttling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do what you are trying to achieve:

**Step-1:** [How to run a stored procedure in sql server every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348899/218408)

**Step-2:** Write the business logic in the stored procedure to check the data

**Step-3:** Call/Post to the web service with CLR integration as discussed [here](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3821271/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-within-SQL-Server.htm)

Or use the [SQL Server Service Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909818/218408)

It is not recommended to implement the way you are planning. Database should only focus on storing the data.

Instead you should have either a CRON service hitting your application on a regular interval. And then from the application query the database and post to the web service as required.

Or, have a scheduled service running within your application and your application can check the DB as above. [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is a library you can use for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks will try the sql server service broker approach